# Unity URP no shadows at edges of inside corner. Light bleeding through walls/edges. Shadows not rendering properly inside

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, shadow, light, urp

I imported some FBX meshes into Unity, but even though the geometry is solid, the shadows on the inside edges do not render correctly, almost as if light is bleeding through the edges, even though it is completely sealed.

Where the deck meets the wall there is light bleeding that isnt supposed to be there:

[light bleeding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0oJp.png)

The floor is not solid, its just a single quad deep, it is neither connected to the walls, but rather the floor extends to the inside of the solid walls.

I tried using a floor that was connected to the walls aswell so its all one linked geometry, but this did not work either as can be seen here:

[solid connected geometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9pqy.png)